# Data Loader Command Line Extract Issue

Tags: data-loader, commandline

I am working on extracting the Partner data from Salesforce using the Data Loader using the command line. I have done upserts using the Data Loader command line however I seem to be running into issues don't the extract.

I have included my bean for the extract.

I have looked over articles and everything I can think of but I seem to keep getting an error. The error that I keep getting is the following:

"com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.UnsupportedDataAccessObjectException: The specified data access object type: csvWriter is not supported"

I can't seem to find anything online that can help me with the issue that I am having. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

```
<bean id="csvExtractPartner"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
    <description>Extract Partner object data.</description>
    <property name="name" value="csvExtractPartner"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\csvExtractPartner.log"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="Username"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.password" value="encryptedPassword"/>
            <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="=\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\key.txt"/><entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT AccountFromId, AccountFrom.AccountNet_Code__c, AccountToId, 
                 AccountTo.AccountNet_Code__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Id, IsDeleted, IsPrimary, LastModifiedById, 
                 LastModifiedDate, OpportunityId, ReversePartnerId, Role, SystemModstamp FROM Partner 
                 WHERE AccountFrom.AccountNet_Code__c != null AND AccountTo.AccountNet_Code__c != null"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="540"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Partner"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\extractPartnerCsvSuccess.csv"/>
            <entry key="process.outputError" value="\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\extractPartnerCsvError.csv"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\ExtractPartner.csv" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWriter" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />
            <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2007-06-06T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
        </map>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Below is my code that worked in case anyone runs into the same issue. I had to add a mapping file as well as change the "extractionRequestSize" entry to "loadBatchSize"

```
<bean id="csvExtractPartner"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
    <description>Extract Partner object data.</description>
    <property name="name" value="csvExtractPartner"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="\SSIS Data Loader\csvExtractPartner.log"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="UserName"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.password" value="password"/>
                 <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\key.txt"/>
                 <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\PartnerMapping.sdl"/>
                 <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT AccountFromId, AccountFrom.AccountNet_Code__c, AccountToId, 
                 AccountTo.AccountNet_Code__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Id, IsDeleted, IsPrimary, LastModifiedById, 
                 LastModifiedDate, OpportunityId, ReversePartnerId, Role, SystemModstamp FROM Partner 
                 WHERE AccountFrom.AccountNet_Code__c != null AND AccountTo.AccountNet_Code__c != null"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="540"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize " value="500"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Partner"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                 <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\extractPartnerCsvSuccess.csv"/>
                 <entry key="process.outputError" value="\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\extractPartnerCsvError.csv"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\ExtractPartner.csv" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite" />
                 <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />
            <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2007-06-06T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
        </map>
    </property>
```